# how to avoid from VSCode removing unused var or imports in Golang

Tags: go

I'm learning golang with latest VSCode, golang plugin and latest golang version.

Goland doesnt let you have unused stuff - for example variable and imports.

Is there a way in VSCode to bypass that?

Thank you :)

Comment: This isn't a VSCode thing, per se. It's part of the standard Go toolchain.. Why do you want unused things?

Comment: Golang project won't build or run if there are unused variables or imports in your project, hence why VS Code removes them. If you're altering code and saving often, maybe think about commenting out lines instead as commented code isn't removed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment that out. The go toolchain won't allow you to keep it and that's a good thing.